# Can I change Height of font in TextView

Tags: android, fonts, textview

I am using this AutoFitTextView : http://www.andreamaglie.com/android-auto-fit-textview/

and it's work fine and all text shown and the font resized ,

[image]

the problem is I want to increase the height since there is available space ,as you see the borders there is space .

**Java code :**

```
   PercentRelativeLayout layout = (PercentRelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.temp_layout);


    AutoTxtV txtV = new AutoTxtV(this);
    txtV.setMaxLines(1);
    txtV.setMinTextSize(1);
    txtV.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,16);
    txtV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    txtV.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.card_name_white));


    txtV.setText("HELLO WORLD HELLO WORLD ABCDEFGHIJKLM");


    layout.addView(txtV);
```

**XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
android:layout_width="279dp"
android:layout_height="405dp"
android:background="@drawable/background">



<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/temp_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_heightPercent="7.5%"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="7.3%"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="4%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="74.5%">
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Is there any way to increase height , maybe change font type ?

**UPDATE (more explain):**

The problem is I want the font "height" to increase not "Size" because if I increase the size the text will  not shown all of it .

The AutoFitTextView, Resize the text "size"**(width and height)** because the "width" of container not enough , I want just decrease the "width" since the width only the problem.

Comment: is that a view or any layout behind textview  ?

Comment: @quicklearner I updated the gist , the parent is layout of type :PercentRelativeLayout

Comment: you should make it wrap content rather than trying textviews height

Answer (score 0):

**These two solve my problem :**

txtV.setScaleY() - change the height

txt.setTextScaleX()